# Cassandra Insert/Update without duplication when you can't rely on the primary key or uuid

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, uuid, insert-update, upsert

Here's the problem.

Our 'customers' are ingested regularly as part of bulk file upload (CSV) from clients. The data we have from them is Name, Address, PostCode, Client Reference Number.

We're saving these into a cassandra 'Customer Table'.

When we do this we assign a UUID which we then use throughout the rest of the system.

The question comes around primary keys… we have two options really
1) UUID as primary key or, 2) composite primary key of (name, address, postcode).

Problem with these options  are: 1) we don't have the UUID at initial insert, it's possible that the 'customers' are duplicated, so how do we de-dupe? Get (select) followed by upsert would be inefficient. 2) has a couple of issues: a) if we perform an update operation there is a possibility that the UUID could be overwritten… b) there is also an issue that name, address, postcode couldn't be updated as they're a composite primary key… a) might not be an issue as a change to UUID will emit an event that will be picked up by other interested services… but kind of removes the point of a UUID… b) we can keep alias (AKA) fields for a customers preferred, or updated details, whilst keeping the original data for reference… though this feels clumsy.

Preferred, and easiest way would be to go for option 1, but without using primary key for initial creation - not sure this is possible? With option 2, we would also need to be able to update all fields but with the exception of the UUID column…

Answer (score 2):

You can only really use the UUID as the partition key if you know if beforehand. You won't be able to insert new customers into the table if you don't have the UUID.

Based on your description, you use the UUID as the unique ID for the rest of your system so it really is the perfect partition key. You will however need to find a solution for the situations where you don't have the customer's UUID. Cheers!

Comment: We've basically come to the conclusion that we're going to have to make a 'get' call. There's really no other way around it as far as we can see... We'll aim to make this as efficient as possible by splitting out the service making the get, the service responding to the get and the service inserting/updating the data. Utilising our kafka queue to gain speed and reducing the processing that the services have to handle.